# css skew element and keep max-width

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, skew

If I distort a container with the skew property, then the short corners are inside the original dimensions and the long corners are outside.
This can be seen in diagram 1 with the blue box.

diagram 1 : [image]

However, I would like the outer corners not to exceed the original width, as in diagram 2 with the red box.

diagram 2 : [image]

I could basically solve this with margin, but the protruding width depends on the length of the container.

Is there a way not to exceed the original width?

I have tried to work with margin, but since the height of the box is not known, I cannot calculate the margin

Comment: I don't think there is any way to solve this using CSS alone; you will have to involve JavaScript to calculate the margin you will need. (And even that could still be problematic, because _adding_ more margin, might then in turn change how much _height_ the content takes.)

Comment: are you obliged to use skew? you can crop the edges with clip-path and get the same result

Answer (score 1):

### Pure CSS

If the height and width of the container `div` are known, you could try something like this, utilising the formula '*a = b x tan(α)*' for finding the additional length after the skew and subtracting it from the overall width of the `div`.

[This source](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/right-triangle-side-angle#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20the%20hypotenuse,the%20length%20of%20the%20hypotenuse.) can better explain the math if you're unfamiliar with it.

You can adjust the width variable in the code snippet to see it work.

```css
body {
  --height: 80px;
  --width: 120px;
  --skew: 20deg;
}

div {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.skewed {
  transform: skew(var(--skew));
  background-color: pink;
  height: var(--height);
  
  /* container width - (height x tan(skew)) */
  width: calc(var(--width) - (var(--height) * tan(var(--skew))));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="skewed"></div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

If the height and width values of the container are not known, you can retrieve them using JavaScript and use the same calculation to set the width of the child element.

Be aware that [Math.tan()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/tan) uses radians instead of degrees so a conversion is required if you're also using degrees.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var positionInfo = container.getBoundingClientRect();

var height = positionInfo.height;
var width = positionInfo.width;

var child = document.getElementById('skewed');

/* same calculation but converting radians to degrees */
child.style.width = (width - (height * Math.tan((20 * Math.PI) / 180))) + "px";
```

```css
body {
  --height: 80px;
  --width: 120px;
  --skew: 20deg;
}

#container {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#skewed {
  transform: skew(20deg);
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="skewed"></div>
</div>
```